# Can we mount a rails 3.0.10 app, under a brand new rails 3.1.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In order to migrate smoothly a Rails 3.0.10 application which need to grow up with many new models and controllers over rails 3.1.1, I wonder if we could just mount the old app under the new 3.1.1 leaving one team implementing the new features, while the other carefully migrate the old 3.0.10 components.

Is that possible ? Is it desirable ? If yes how can we do it ?

Any idea or experiences is welcome.

UPDATE

... we also are in a phase which every programmer is starting a new feature, with no resources for porting currently. So I said, way don't start with many brand new self contained/tested apps (rack + sinara + old rails 3.0) driven by (mounted on) rails 3.1.1 working as a router/container ?

I've in mind something like Paul Dix describe in his ["Service-Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368) book.

New features, can also be started over Rails 3.1.1, on top of that old 3.0 app, until the first programmer will be ready to start migration ... what do you say ?

Luca

Comment: If you don't have the resources to do a full port now, wait until you have the resources to do it.  Any middleground is overly complex.  You don't gain anything except complexity by trying to run an existing rails 3.0 codebase inside of a rails 3.1 app. It won't make upgrading any easier.

Comment: I'd also like to note that your situation is not unique.  There are many situations where people want to upgrade rails and don't have the time right now.  Generally, they wait.

Comment: this blog-post might help for rails-beginners https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/ruby-on-rails-order-of-migration-generator-matters-in-initial-design/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not doing it this way.  What you end up doing is doubling your work - you now have to test every feature in multiple codebases, for little benefit.

Just upgrade the app from 3 -> 3.1 and move on with your day.  It shouldn't be hard, 3.1 is a point release and should be mostly backwards compatible.

Historically the main issue with upgrading has been 3rd party library dependencies besides Rails - they often break when rails is updated, and then you have to either fix them, rewrite them yourself, switch to another one that works on the new rails version, or just wait to upgrade until they are compatible, all which may be undesirable.

Fortunately, I don't think a lot of gems broke in between rails 3 and 3.1 so you shouldn't have that issue.

Edit: if you're concerned about the changes to css/javascript/html in 3.1, I can only imagine you're assuming the asset pipeline changes things.  in my experience, it doesn't.  The asset pipeline, to my knowledge, is mostly optional.  I think you can still reference css/javascript in the same manner as rails 3.0 if you want

Comment: For most apps, even complex ones, it should only take a few hours (and a little bit of Ops work because 3.1 requires a javascript runtime) to upgrade from 3 to 3.1

Comment: ... gems a part, we're most afraid of javascript/css layout and views. In our exp. that's the less portable component while migrating r3 to r3.1.1

Comment: ... se UPDATE in the main Question